# Python ValueError in this code

Tags: python, numpy

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "project.py", line 35, in <module>
    cells = [np.hsplit(row,100) for row in np.vsplit(img,50)]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/shape_base.py", line 623, in vsplit
    return split(ary, indices_or_sections, 0)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/shape_base.py", line 508, in split
    'array split does not result in an equal division')
ValueError: array split does not result in an equal division
```

code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

SZ=20
bin_n = 16 # Number of bins

svm_params = dict( kernel_type = cv2.SVM_LINEAR,
                    svm_type = cv2.SVM_C_SVC,
                    C=2.67, gamma=5.383 )

affine_flags = cv2.WARP_INVERSE_MAP|cv2.INTER_LINEAR

def deskew(img):
    m = cv2.moments(img)
    if abs(m['mu02']) < 1e-2:
        return img.copy()
    skew = m['mu11']/m['mu02']
    M = np.float32([[1, skew, -0.5*SZ*skew], [0, 1, 0]])
    img = cv2.warpAffine(img,M,(SZ, SZ),flags=affine_flags)
    return img

def hog(img):
    gx = cv2.Sobel(img, cv2.CV_32F, 1, 0)
    gy = cv2.Sobel(img, cv2.CV_32F, 0, 1)
    mag, ang = cv2.cartToPolar(gx, gy)
    bins = np.int32(bin_n*ang/(2*np.pi))    # quantizing binvalues in (0...16)
    bin_cells = bins[:10,:10], bins[10:,:10], bins[:10,10:], bins[10:,10:]
    mag_cells = mag[:10,:10], mag[10:,:10], mag[:10,10:], mag[10:,10:]
    hists = [np.bincount(b.ravel(), m.ravel(), bin_n) for b, m in zip(bin_cells, mag_cells)]
    hist = np.hstack(hists)     # hist is a 64 bit vector
    return hist

img = cv2.imread('digits.png',0)

cells = [np.hsplit(row,100) for row in np.vsplit(img,50)]

# First half is trainData, remaining is testData
train_cells = [ i[:50] for i in cells ]
test_cells = [ i[50:] for i in cells]

######     Now training      ########################

deskewed = [map(deskew,row) for row in train_cells]
hogdata = [map(hog,row) for row in deskewed]
trainData = np.float32(hogdata).reshape(-1,64)
responses = np.float32(np.repeat(np.arange(10),250)[:,np.newaxis])

svm = cv2.SVM()
svm.train(trainData,responses, params=svm_params)
svm.save('svm_data.dat')

######     Now testing      ########################

deskewed = [map(deskew,row) for row in test_cells]
hogdata = [map(hog,row) for row in deskewed]
testData = np.float32(hogdata).reshape(-1,bin_n*4)
result = svm.predict_all(testData)

#######   Check Accuracy   ########################
mask = result==responses
correct = np.count_nonzero(mask)
print correct*100.0/result.size
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You have to show your code so we can help you

Comment: very hard to help with errors when we cant see whats causing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error and a search of the code (for `split) the error must occur in

```
[np.hsplit(row,100) for row in np.vsplit(img,50)]
```

What's the shape of `img`?  The error indicates that it (`img.shape[0]`) is not a multiple of `50`.

Answer (score 0):

You probably trying to break a vector into lines. However, make sure that tthe number of elements of the vector is a multiple of the number of lines you are trying to break it into. You can't, for example, split a (5, 1) vector into 2 lines. In this case, the size of each `row` has to be a multiple of 100.